# Сравнение двух таблиц по id postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо сравнить две таблицы по id, первая таблица эталонная состоит из одного столбца id (значения 1-2000000), вторая таблица с данными 5 столбцов, один из которых id.
Необходимо сравнить таблицы по id и вывести значения эталонной таблицы, которые отсутствуют в таблице с данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [оператором EXCEPT](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/except.php):

```
SELECT id FROM standard_table
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM data_table;
```